# Knockout visible binding in a modal

Tags: knockout.js

I have a modal that needs to display text based on whether a property in my view model is true or not. I have an ajax call set up to determine that information but I'm not very familiar with knockout and need some help with the binding.

I need to display everything in the "eligible" div if the property is true and if its false, display everything in the "ineligible" div instead. Below is a streamlined portion of it.

```
<div class="modal-body" id="orderStatus">

    <div class= "eligible" data-bind="visible: Eligible">
        <p>text</p>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          //button
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class= "ineligible" data-bind="visible: !Eligible">
         <p>text</p>
         <div class="modal-footer">
             //button
         </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are the divs really different, or do they just differ by class?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use what @Josh Stevens mentioned, you can simply define another variable in your model and set this variable by subscribing '`Eligible`'  then you still will be able to use visible in order to show and hide DOM for both eligible and ineligible observable variables.

in your model add :

```
 self.Ineligible = ko.observable(false);

 self.Eligible.subscribe(function (value) {
   self.Ineligible(!value);
 });
```

in your view change :

```
<div class="modal-body" id="orderStatus">

  <div class="eligible" data-bind="visible: Eligible">
    <p>text</p>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      //button
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ineligible" data-bind="visible: Ineligible">
    <p>text</p>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      //button
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Edit :** 
Quick way : 
  just add `<div class="ineligible" data-bind="visible: Eligible() == 0 ">` in your view so whenever Eligible is false,the result of this comparison would be true

```
  <div class="modal-body" id="orderStatus">
      <div class="eligible" data-bind="visible: Eligible">
         <p>text</p>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              //button
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ineligible" data-bind="visible: Eligible() == 0 ">
         <p>text</p>
         <div class="modal-footer">
              //button
         </div>
      </div>  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not use a `visible binding` as a false clause it has to be true. To fix this i would not use a `visible binding` i would wrap it in a `ko if` it is the way this situation should be done. As knockout updates each time the value changes this will work the same as the visible clause.

```
<div class="modal-body" id="orderStatus">
<!-- ko if: Eligible() -->
    <div class= "eligible">
        <p>text</p>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          //button
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- /ko-->
<!-- ko if: !Eligible() -->
    <div class= "ineligible" data-bind="visible: !Eligible">
         <p>text</p>
         <div class="modal-footer">
             //button
         </div>
    </div>
<!-- /ko-->
</div>
```

If your worried about the DOM removing the element each time you can use the `css binding` and add a class to your element.

```
<div class="modal-body" id="orderStatus">
    <div class= "eligible" data-bind="css: { hide: Eligible() }">
        <p>text</p>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          //button
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class= "ineligible" data-bind="css: { hide: !Eligible() }">
         <p>text</p>
         <div class="modal-footer">
             //button
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide { display:none; }
```

This will work just like the visible binding.

Comment: the reason i was hesitant about using 'if' was the text within the paragraph tags comes from a different site. Since visible doesnt remove elements from the DOM, I thought this was a safer bet. Am I mistaken? In either case, I'm not sure what the actual knockout has to look like for this data coming from the viewModel.

Comment: you have defined 'Eligible' as a ko.observable haven't you?

Comment: Yeah, but im not sure where to go from there

Comment: what do you mean? start applying your knockout bindings etc. and then allow user to change that value.. you can put 'eligible' observable as a 'checked' binding on a checkbox and it will update true to false each time simulating your hide and show state.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't explaining correctly? I have this property in my viewmodel:
public bool IsEligible {get;set;}

whether thats true or false is determined serverside. I get this information to the front end through an ajax call and if its true, i have to display that eligible div, if not, the ineligible div. I'm not sure how to write the knockout behind that conditional logic on my view. If I were just using Razor, I'd write @if (Model.IsEligible){...} else{...} on the data-bind line

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure how to write the knockout behind that conditional logic
>   on my view. If I were just using Razor, I'd write @if
>   (Model.IsEligible){...} else{...} on the data-bind line

You could use something like this in your razor view. If you have an @section scripts {} defined that links to your head section in HTML. You need to setup a JS var so you can call it in your JS file where you are instantiating ko.

```
<script>
    window.source = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
</script
```

I think this is what you are looking for...?

https://jsfiddle.net/24k3dLmb/5/

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is perfect. All you need now is to set the knockout ViewModel its Eligible observable to the boolean value you receive from the server. Try the following:

```
YourViewModel = function(item) {
    var _self = this;

    _self.Eligible = ko.observable(@Json.Encode(Model.IsEligible));
}
```

The above is in case your Eligible property can still change client-side. If you don't need this, you don't need it to be an observable and your code would become:

```
YourViewModel = function(item) {
    var _self = this;

    _self.Eligible = @Json.Encode(Model.IsEligible);
}
```

Comment: Please flag this as the answer in case it answered your question.